# How do I unset a variable in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a plugin that sets a global variable and checks it each time the plugin is loaded to avoid loading itself multiple times.  I would like to allow reloading of the plugin (allow reloading of the plugin) without altering the plugin itself.  The plugin simply checks to see that it's variable exists (i.e. `exists('g:var_name')`)—is there a way to unset said variable so that the `exists()` check returns false?

p.s. I don't want to alter the plugin itself because I use [pathogen with git submodules](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/) pointed at the plugin's repo.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I found the [Vim documentation for vimscript](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html), which has a section on [variables](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.2):

> To delete a variable use the ":unlet" command.  Example:

```
:unlet s:count
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to `:unlet g:var_name`.

The problem with this is that if the functions defined in the plugin are not defined with `function!` then you're going to get lots of errors when the plugin is sourced for a second time.  The plugin may also be doing initial setup that could get fouled up by running it twice.

In general, if the plugin author has added a loaded trap it's probably there for a reason.

Comment: True, I am treading into dangerous waters by doing this.  Specifically, I use the [Mark](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1238) plugin which seems to get clobbered whenever I load a session using [sessionman.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2010).

Comment: Instead of `unlet g:loaded_mark` you could `let g:force_reload_mark = 1` because of how his test is constructed.  It looks like the plugin is written with re-sourcing in mind because of the fact that any colorscheme changes kill his plugin.  He states this in the readme on the script page.

Comment: Here are two additions: 1. If you define anonymous function (`function dict.fname`) then instead of using `function!` you should just empty `dict` (like `let dict={}`). 2. If you define normal function, then to avoid errors when resourcing plugin you can use `delfunction` command. Both actions are used by `LoadCommand reload ...` from vimpluginloader and `call frawor#Reload(...)` from frawor (it is required that you use these frameworks to be able to reload your plugin).

Comment: Whoops, I had linked to the wrong Mark script on vim.org—I'm actually using [Ingo Karkat's Mark](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666), which doesn't have `g:force_reload_mark`.