# how to unlet variables in vim?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I am trying to clean up solarized's 'let' space pollution so that I can switch to another theme from solarized. Currently, solarized corrupts subsequent colourschemes (eg solarized --> superman).

However, I seem to be unable to unlet solarized's variables. I have done

```
    unlet! g:solarized_hitrail 
    unlet! g:solarized_visibility
    unlet! g:solarized_termtrans
    unlet! g:solarized_underline
    unlet! g:solarized_diffmode
    unlet! g:solarized_italic
    unlet! g:solarized_degrade
    unlet! g:solarized_bold
    unlet! g:solarized_termcolors
    unlet! g:solarized_menu
    unlet! g:solarized_contrast

    unlet! a:solarized_hitrail
    unlet! a:solarized_visibility
    unlet! a:solarized_termtrans
    unlet! a:solarized_underline
    unlet! a:solarized_diffmode
    unlet! a:solarized_italic
    unlet! a:solarized_degrade
    unlet! a:solarized_bold
    unlet! a:solarized_termcolors
    unlet! a:solarized_menu
    unlet! a:solarized_contrast

    unlet! l:solarized_hitrail
    unlet! l:solarized_visibility
    unlet! l:solarized_termtrans
    unlet! l:solarized_underline
    unlet! l:solarized_diffmode
    unlet! l:solarized_italic
    unlet! l:solarized_degrade
    unlet! l:solarized_bold
    unlet! l:solarized_termcolors
    unlet! l:solarized_menu
    unlet! l:solarized_contrast

    unlet! b:solarized_hitrail
    unlet! b:solarized_visibility
    unlet! b:solarized_termtrans
    unlet! b:solarized_underline
    unlet! b:solarized_diffmode
    unlet! b:solarized_italic
    unlet! b:solarized_degrade
    unlet! b:solarized_bold
    unlet! b:solarized_termcolors
    unlet! b:solarized_menu
    unlet! b:solarized_contrast

    unlet! w:solarized_hitrail
    unlet! w:solarized_visibility
    unlet! w:solarized_termtrans
    unlet! w:solarized_underline
    unlet! w:solarized_diffmode
    unlet! w:solarized_italic
    unlet! w:solarized_degrade
    unlet! w:solarized_bold
    unlet! w:solarized_termcolors
    unlet! w:solarized_menu
    unlet! w:solarized_contrast

    unlet! t:solarized_hitrail
    unlet! t:solarized_visibility
    unlet! t:solarized_termtrans
    unlet! t:solarized_underline
    unlet! t:solarized_diffmode
    unlet! t:solarized_italic
    unlet! t:solarized_degrade
    unlet! t:solarized_bold
    unlet! t:solarized_termcolors
    unlet! t:solarized_menu
    unlet! t:solarized_contrast
```

... and all these variables remain as "let" variables, and other colorschemes continue to not work properly. The problems caused by solarized are extensive, and also involve changing and removing all kinds of theme linkages as well. Here, I just can not see how, or why, I can not unlet a variable.

I am also aware of [How do I unset a variable in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755850/how-do-i-unset-a-variable-in-vim) , but that says "use unlet", which is not working.

If anyone can give me any pointers, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, I am trying to unlet these solarized variables when running a different, subsequent, colorscheme.

Comment: `:unlet` is exactly what you need for getting rid of variables but those variables are only used by solarized: **they have no effect whatsoever outside of solarized.** Your problems are caused by their *usage*, not by their *existence*.

Comment: @ramaini, yes, yes, of course, but I can still not unlet these variables from solarized. I can not see why, or how, I can not unlet these variables. I just don't get it (the non-unlet).